# Array of array references

Tags: c#, string, reference

I have three string arrays:

```
private readonly string[] PMCTableColumnNames = new string[] { "PMCIP", "Description", "Cam1ReferencePoints", "Cam2ReferencePoints", "DataserverIP" };
private readonly string[] PMDTableColumnNames = new string[] { "PMDIP", "Description" };
private readonly string[] PMDZonesTableColumnNames = new string[] { "PMDIP", "Description", "Zone" };
```

I want to construct an array that points to these arrays as:

```
private var[] ArrayReferences = new var[] { PMCTableColumnNames, PMDTableColumnNames, PMDZonesTableColumnNames };
```

When i put index to this (ArrayReferences) array, i want to get all elements of the specific array like this:

```
string[] _PMDTableColumnNames = ArrayReferences[1];
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Why are you using `var[]`? And are you telling us that `string[] _PMDTableColumnNames = ArrayReferences[1];` is not working?

Comment: @Oded: I believe it is legal to use `var[]` here, since the compiler can infer the type?

Comment: @carlpett - I don't believe it is a valid use.

Comment: No, i write "var" because i want to express my idea. I know that it can't be "var".

Comment: Then don't post code that can't even compile (unless that's the point of the question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an array of arrays:

```
private string[][] ArrayReferences;
```

Note you'll have to initialise `ArrayReferences` in the constructor since you can't reference the other arrays in the field initialiser. i.e.

```
public class ClassName
{
    private readonly string[] PMCTableColumnNames = new string[] { "PMCIP", "Description", "Cam1ReferencePoints", "Cam2ReferencePoints", "DataserverIP" };
    private readonly string[] PMDTableColumnNames = new string[] { "PMDIP", "Description" };
    private readonly string[] PMDZonesTableColumnNames = new string[] { "PMDIP", "Description", "Zone" };

    private string[][] ArrayReferences;

    public ClassName()
    {
        ArrayReferences = new string[][] { PMCTableColumnNames, PMDTableColumnNames, PMDZonesTableColumnNames };
    }

    void SomeMethod()
    {
        string[] _PMDTableColumnNames = ArrayReferences[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: @petre - Should? That's not a requirement of the language. How do you mean "should"?

Comment: @Oded because the first line of this answer gives an error: *Cannot access non-static field in static context* if the three arrays are not static.

Comment: by the way: the term for an array of arrays is **jagged array**.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[][] ArrayReferences = new [] { PMCTableColumnNames, PMDTableColumnNames, PMDZonesTableColumnNames };
```

or just

```
var ArrayReferences = new [] { PMCTableColumnNames, PMDTableColumnNames, PMDZonesTableColumnNames };
```

should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can use [ArrayList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) class it's meant for this kind of purposes.

Comment: If the collection length is fixed, an array is fine. If you need to dynamically modify the collection, then a generic `List<T>` is preferable to `ArrayList`.

Comment: No I don't think so, `ArrayList` has `add` method by which you can add elements to your `ArrayList` dynamically, And you don't need to specify the length of the `ArrayList` in advance. But yes for a typesafe list `List<T>` is a better option.

Comment: @yogi might be a good idea to read @lee's answer again, and read up on [`List`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) and [`ArrayList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx).